# Stop scroll when I move mouse or wheel

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a problem, I'm using 2 types of scrolling (down and up)

How I can prevent conflict between scrolls?

```
 $('form#slider img.img').click(function () {

            var index = $(this).prevAll('img').length; 
            $('div#immagini img').attr('src', imgArray[index]);
            show(0);


            //animation sroll down
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $('html, body').delay(200).get(0).scrollHeight
            }, 2000);
```

So my body scrool down;

When i click the function :

```
    switch (index) {

                    case 0:
                        //load image from array
                        $('div#immagini img').attr('src', imgArray[0]);

                        $("#ris3").click(function () {
                              //scroll top
                            $('html, body').delay(400).animate({ scrollTop: '0px' }, 2000);

                        });

                        $("#ris1").click(function () {
                               //scroll top
                            $('html, body').delay(400).animate({ scrollTop: '0px' }, 2000);
                            $('div#immagini img').attr('src', errArray[0]);
                        });

                        $("#ris2").click(function () {
                             //scroll top
                            $('html, body').delay(400).animate({ scrollTop: '0px' }, 2000);
                            $('div#immagini img').attr('src', errArray[0]);
                        });

                        $('html,body').scroll(function () {
                            $(this).stop(true, false);
                        });    

                        break;
```

Thanks very mouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can prevent the mouse wheel being used with

```
jQuery(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hSjK6/

Then to only stop scrolling when something is happening you can use a boolean e.g.

```
if(scroll)
{
scroll = false;
$('html, body').delay(400).animate({ scrollTop: '0px' }, 2000,function(){scroll = true});
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi I have updated my fiddle to incorporate a little more of what I expect you are trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/hSjK6/3/

Hope this helps a little more

Comment: it's quite hard to test without the html but at a quick glance you need to move the  var scroll = true;
            jQuery(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
                if (!scroll) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
out of the click function

Comment: It is normal that the scroll of the images is very slow? 
Minimum 5 seconds